# How to Play video data coming from server in iOS

Tags: ios, video

I am working on iOS application which needs showing video coming from server. Video data is coming in packets and its H264 encoded Format. After looking for AVFoundation option I didnt find any thing which plays video data received in packets from socket connection. If some one could point me in right direction it would be of very helpful. I am stuck over this for couple of days.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026942/how-to-play-local-and-server-url-video-in-iphone

Comment: Use `MPMoviePlayerVideoController`.

Comment: have a look at [here[(http://stackoverflow.com/a/21702554/2515572) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699366/2515572).

Comment: @iTroyd23 Thanks for the reply. video is live video data bytes encoded in H264 format. There's no URL or such. MPMoviePlayerVideoController uses URL? I am receiving data in buffers and i need to play that data as its coming.

Comment: Log the input and can you show me the part of exact input?

Comment: Convert buffer data to image and display the image in imageView.

Comment: @iTroyd23 H264 encoded data will get converted to image?

Comment: Log the input and can you show me the part of exact input?